# Estoy intentando trabajar con arreglos en C, pero me sale un error al compilarlo

Tags: array, c, bucle-for

```
int productos[10];
int i; 

printf("\n* Precio de Productos *\n");

for ( i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    printf("Escriba el precio del producto N°%i: ", i);
    scanf("%i", &productos[i]);
}

printf("Los productos recogidos fueron: ");

for ( i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    printf("Poducto N°%i = %i \n", i, productos[i]);
}
```

El programa se trata de hacer un pequeño algoritmo, que almacene 10 precios. Pero en el segundo bucle for, estoy intentando imprimirlos, a ver si si funciona correctamente, pero lo que me aparece al final, es un mensaje diciendo: zsh: abort. Que podría ser eso?. Agradecería sus respuestas.

Comment: Esto no es un error al compilarlo, es un error al correrlo. Tu array es de 10 elementos, entonces los indices validos van de 0 a 9, no de 1 a 10. Al acceder al indice 10 estas accediendo a memoria que no tienes asignada, cayendo en comportamiento indefinido. En ese punto es tan valido que tu programa funcione, que no funcione, que funcione pero lo cierre el sistema operativo como parece ser este caso, o cualquier otra cosa.

Answer (score 2):

> > Estoy intentando trabajar con arreglos en C, pero me sale un error al compilarlo

No es un **error de compilación**, el programa compila y genera el ejecutable. Si el programa *abortó* fue por un **error de ejecución**.

> > Pero en el segundo bucle for, estoy intentando imprimirlos, a ver si si funciona correctamente, pero lo que me aparece al final, es un mensaje diciendo: zsh: abort.

Los *arrays* en C empiezan a partir del índice `0` y terminan en `N - 1` (donde `N` es el tamaño del array). Por ejemplo, si el tamaño del array es de 10 elementos, los índices válidos son de `0` a `9` `(10 - 1)`.

No puedes leer ni escribir en índices que no estén en el rango de `0` a `9`, si lo haces, es un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido), esto significa que el programa puede funcionar o puede que no o puede que funcione más tarde o puede que el programa te lleve a [esto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsTepMs0co8). Por algo se llama "comportamiento indefinido", justamente porque no hay un resultado "definido", no la hay. Nunca pero nunca dejes que tu programa se comporte de manera indefinida, porque puede pasar cualquier cosa.

Si te pasas de los límites del array, puede pasar varias cosas:

- Acceder a una dirección de memoria que no fue asignada al programa, a esto se le llama [segment fault](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso), al ser un error de ejecución, evidentemente se detiene el programa, ya no funcionará.. Los sistemas operativos modernos matarán al programa al instante, por lo que el programa abortará.
- Sobrescribir la propia memoria del programa. Dios Mio, este caso es el peor y es difícil de depurar, espero QUE TU PROGRAMA NUNCA TENGA ESTE COMPORTAMIENTO. Puedes ver un ejemplo [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer).

Por lo que esto:

```c
for ( i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
```

Está mal, muy mal, lo debes corregir así:

```c
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Al final el código quedaría así:

```c
int productos[10]; 
int i;

printf("\n* Precio de Productos *\n");

for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("Escriba el precio del producto N°%i: ", i);
    scanf("%i", &productos[i]);
}

printf("Los productos recogidos fueron: ");

for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("Poducto N°%i = %i \n", i, productos[i]);
}
```

### Observación

Intenta minimizar el ciclo de vida de las variables:

```c
int productos[10]; 

printf("\n* Precio de Productos *\n");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("Escriba el precio del producto N°%i: ", i);
    scanf("%i", &productos[i]);
}

printf("Los productos recogidos fueron: ");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("Poducto N°%i = %i \n", i, productos[i]);
}
```

Es más simple declarar las variables cuando se *utilicen*, en lugar, de declararlo todo al principio.

Comment: Ya entiendo, se me olvido esa parte de la documentación, por eso el bucle 'for' al llegar al 10, simplemente abortaba. Agradezco mucho tu respuesta, y tomaré en cuenta todas las sugerencias y correcciones. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Arreglé tu código. Por lo que se ve sos nuevo en la programación.
Te dejo un tip, la próxima vez que subas un código a StackOverflow no olvides poner todo lo que es relevante para que alguien te ayude con tu problema. En el código que pasaste faltan cosas como el array que cargas/mostras "productos"  en los bucles "for" y la declaración de la variable "i".

Por acá te dejo el código con el problema solucionado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        float productos[10];
        int i;
    
        printf("\n* Precio de Productos *\n");
    
        for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            printf("Escriba el precio del producto N°%i: ", i);
            scanf("%f", &productos[i]);
        }
    
            printf("Los productos recogidos fueron: \n");
    
        for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            printf("Producto N°%i = %.2f \n", i, productos[i]);
        }
    }
```

Correcciones:

1. Variable "productos" declarada como flotante. Si vas manejarte con precios recuerda que usaras "." así que es necesario que utilices flotante, si usas enteros "int" te saltará error.
2. Variable "i" declarada.
3. En los bucles "for" settea 0 el valor inicial de "i". Recuerda que la primer posición de los array es 0 ! .
4. "/n" colocado al final del tercer printf().
5. "%.2f" en el cuarto printf. Esto es para limitar que solo se muestren 2 decimales después de la coma
6. Primer scanf() "&i" cambiado por "%f".

Espero te sirva.

Saludos!

Comment: SI el array es de 10 elementos, los indices validos van de 0 a 9, en tu codigo accedes al indice 10 leyendo memoria que no tienes asignada. Las condiciones de los loop tienen que ser `i < 10` o `i != 10`, no `i <= 10`.

Comment: De hecho si estoy comenzando, me fue de gran ayuda cada una de tus correcciones, muchas gracias enserio. Tomaré en cuenta los tips y las sugerencias, saludos.